# Как правильно использовать AlarmManager?

Tags: java, android, android-alarm-manager

Есть приложение которое регулярно делает запрос на сервер с помощью AlarmManager при определенном ответе от сервера показывает AlertDialog. Когда  выполняется метод onReceive если AlertDialog на экране он закрывается и выполняется очередной запрос если запрос положительный окно опять открывается. После пары перезапусков AlertDialog метод onReceive уже не выполняется.

```
 private void RegisterAlarmBroadcast() {
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        // private static final String TAG = "Alarm Example Receiver";
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if  (isStopped){
                UnregisterAlarmBroadcast();
            }
            if (alarm != null) {
                if (alarm.isShowing()) {
                    DialogStop();
                }
            }
            setAlarm(delay, pendingIntent);
            new XmlSending().execute(msgGetWarningAlarm);
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("sample"));
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, new Intent("sample"), 0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
    setAlarm(delay, pendingIntent);
}

private void setAlarm(int delayInMillis, PendingIntent sender){
    final int SDK_INT = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    long timeInMillis = (System.currentTimeMillis() + delayInMillis) / 1000 * 1000;     //> example

    if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, sender);
    }
    else if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= SDK_INT  && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, sender);
    }
    else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, sender);
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "New alarm!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void UnregisterAlarmBroadcast() {
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    getBaseContext().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

Подскажите как правильно реализовать этот процесс? Информация в AlertDialog может меняться потому ничего не придумал как его перезапускать но оно перезапускается только пару раз, а дальше висит без срабатываний метода onReceive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BroadcastReceiver` не зря каждый раз получет `Context` как параметр

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
```

Я не вижу, как создается `AlertDialog`, но все очень похоже что происходит рассинхронизация контекстов, тот контекст что использовался для создания `AlertDialog` уже не существует.
Пересмотрите подход, используйте контекст из `onReceive`, он каждый раз может быть иным.

Comment: Изменил ресивер, теперь при создании `AlertDialog` использую контекст `allertContext` который обновляется при выполнении `mReceiver`. Но ничего не поменялось. `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(allertContext); AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); 
        dialog.show(); `

Comment: Более детально изучив процес. Выходит что у меня выпоняеться метод `alarmManager.set()` например, но в ресивере он уже не появляеться хотя контекст использую обновленный.

Comment: Не понятно как у вас происходит синхронизация ресивера и сетевой операции. Каждый сам по себе асинхронно работает, могут создаваться патовые ситуации.